# Why in crypto casinos payment is mainly in bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core, payment, ethereum, gambling

Why in crypto casinos payment is mainly in bitcoin, ethereum, tron and other cryptocurrencies, but there is no payment in stablecoins? Isn't it more profitable to accept payments in usdt, usdc, busd? So you will not be afraid because of the fall in the rate of cryptocurrencies

Answer (score 1):

Some gambling websites accept USDT however it be could freezed and controlled by [Tether](https://tether.to/en/about-us). So, users and owners of gambling websites would normally prefer a cryptocurrency like bitcoin that is censorship resistant.

Nobody cares about 1-2% change in price when they are gambling on events in which they could even lose all.